# Doing an async call within a dynamicHelper (use res.locals) in Express 3.x

Tags: node.js, express, helper

I want to create a dynamicHelper using res.locals .
eg:

```
res.locals.someHelper = function(arg){
  Model.find(arg, function(err, docs){
    return docs;
  });
}
```

Well, I will use it in any views. eg:

```
- each item in someHelper(arg)
  = item
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not do async call in view helpers. You should prepare all those async data already before you call your view render, so you can just use them synchronously.

To do this, you can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module in your router.

```
async.parallel({
  name: function (callback) {
    Model.find(arg, callback);
  },
  age: function (callback) {
    Model.find(arg, callback);
  }
}, function (err, results) {
  for (var i in results) {
    res.local[i] = results[i];
  }
  return next();
});
```